# View is completely black for few seconds in first launch in ios, swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, splash-screen, branch.io

1. I was requested to show two `Splash Screens` when app launch. one
   for a specific group of customers and other for another group of
   customers. As I know, **Apple** doesn't allow to show two splash
   screens, because it is already signed to `Bundle`. so I decided to
   use an `UIImageView` and change the image by `checking` the group.
2. To check the group I used  `deep links` which provide by the `Branch.io`. when someone came from the `referral` link which we created, it show one `image` and if someone came from normal way we show another `image` as `launch` image, instead of splash screen. it works properly.
3. But when the first launch it shows `Black Screen` for five to six seconds(considerable time) and show the image.
4. If it is not the first time, it works properly.(black screen for 1 to 2 second.)

Below is the way which I used to check the condition and show the `image` in another `viewController`.

in `AppDelegate`, inside the `didFinishLaunchWithOption` method I checked with `branch` like below.

let branch : Branch = Branch.getInstance()
//        branch.setDebug()

```
    branch.initSessionWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions) { (params, error) in
        if error == nil {

            let clickedBranchlink : Bool = params["+clicked_branch_link"] as! Bool
            let isfirstSession : Bool = params["+is_first_session"] as! Bool


            if clickedBranchlink == true {
                 let theReferrer : String = params["referrer"] as! String
                if theReferrer == "groupA" {


               // in here I checked the group and set userdefault values and navigate to the view which the image view has and show the image according to this condition.
                }

}
}
```

> **NOTE:** is there a way to increase the process of this and reduce the
>   black screen. do I do this inside a main thread. because first time it
>   avoid to go through the `branch.initSessionWithLaunchOptions` and then
>   it goes through it. hope your help with this.

Comment: maybe start with a static splash and then change later the image to the targetgroup image.

Comment: have a look here - maybe this helps? https://www.raywenderlich.com/133224/how-to-create-an-uber-splash-screen

Comment: Is this 5-6 second delay for _every_ launch when the app is not running in the background, or just the first time after installing the app?

Comment: just for first time

Answer (score 0):

This initSessionWithLaunchOptions will be called every time you launch the app and the app is not in the background. Given your observation that the issue only occurs the first time the app is installed, my hunch is that you have code running in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions before the Branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions function is called.

The Branch initialization process involves sending a network request and then waiting for a response, so this is always going to take some time - but there will be no difference in the time it takes on install vs. any other open. Start this asynchronous Branch initialization as quickly as possible, before any other code in didFinishLaunchtingWithOptions executes, and you should be able to reduce the time before the splash page displays. This should eliminate any variability in the time it takes to display the splash image that you believe may be related to Branch.